# SimpliPy - Output File not an option

Tags: qgis

I am trying to implement line simplification on a polyline dataset using SimpliPy in QGIS but there is not an option for the output dataset. There are two notes mentioned in the plugins repository ( https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/simplipy/ ):
- You must have installed Shapely 1.2.18 or you will get an error installing or using this plugin.
- The output can only be saved to a "New layer" for now. (The Output:Field isn't working).

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the plugin:

The "output field" section was an option that appeared in versions < 0.30 but was never implemented and removed in 0.31. If you update the plugin version to the latest one you will see it's not there (I removed it basically because I didn't have time to manage how to make it work).

About LineStrings simplification: You are right, it's not implemented. Since it's very similar to simplifying polygons I will include it in the next version of the plugin.

Comment: I've released a new version of SimpliPy (0.40) which now supports LineString and MultiLineStrings.

Comment: Thanks a lot Albert. I would like to ask you two questions: 1. Do I need to run the plugin and then Save As the output file? 2. Can I see the execution time of the operation?

Comment: @VasilisKaloyirou 1. Yes, you will need to use QGIS exporting tools to export the new SimplipY X layer. 2. In the current version you can't see it, but I'll include it on the next update.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried the plugin but it seems like it does not support lines

```
Not supported geometry type: LineString
```

It works fine with polygons though (just click Start and it adds a layer with the simplification output as shown in the following screenshot)

[image]